# Align Foundation 5 tabs in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Im trying to align the out of the box Tabs which come with Foundation 5. For some reason by default they are aligned to the left and i cant figure out how i can get these to align to the center of the screen. The code i am working with is fairly simple (the bog standard tab markup)

**Example:**

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
        <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
        <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Live Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/7YxLg/

So what i am aiming for is for the two tabs to be centered in the middle of the screen instead of to the left can this be done?

Answer (score 11):

I got the tabs to center and play nice with foundation through the following SCSS:

```
ul.tabs {
    text-align: center;
    li {
        float: none !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

If you're using plain CSS:

```
ul.tabs {
    text-align: center;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Benefits:** You don't need to specify a width, which can cause problems with responsiveness.  You also don't need an extra div.  This solution is specific to foundation as well.

**Explaination:**
Normally, adding text-align: center; to the ul's css would center the li elements.  But, foundation's default css adds float: left to li's inside ul.tabs.  We clear this with float: none !important and realign the li elements in an inline block.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, using the magic of auto-margins.

Figure out the overall width of the elements, then encase the lot in a div.

CSS:

```
#tabsDiv
{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Then in the HTML, put all your code into that div.

Comment: Yeah i guess that would be the most simply solution. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem. Most of the time the most simple solution is the best, especially for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Looks like you have answered this in the RUSH of answering.