# Align Foundation 5 clearing lightbox items to the center

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to align the items in a clearing lightbox to the center. The lightbox aligns the items to the left for default. Here is the current situation:

[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548990/align-foundation-5-tabs-in-the-middle-of-the-screen) answer  you can align them in the tabs component using

```
float: none !important;
 display: inline-block;
```

But for the lightbox it just produces an erratic behavior where the thumbnails are in an apparently random position yet center aligned horizontally:

[image]

So i wonder how to make the items aligned to the center and not all to the left.

Here is the relevant code:

CSS:

```
[class*="clearing-thumbs"]
{
/* top  right  bottom left*/
    margin:  5% 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.25 0 0.5rem 0;
}

  [class*="clearing-thumbs"] > li
{
    padding: 0.025 0 0.5rem 0;
/*
    float: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    top:0%;
*/
}
```

HTML/JS:

```
 function load(listaSucursales.data)
{

var output = '<div class="row"><div class="small-11 small-centered columns" >';
        output += '<ul class="clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>';

        for(var x in listaSucursales.data)
        {

        output+='<li> <div class="square">'+ listaSucursales.data[x].NOMBRE +"</div></li> ";

        }

        output+= '</ul> </div></div>';

    document.getElementById("mainContent").innerHTML=output;
}
```

Comment: Study this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/, then try `display: flex` for the `ul` and aligning for the `li`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Niloct suggestion this code allowed me to align the items as i needed:

```
[class*="clearing-thumbs"]
{
    margin:  5% 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.25 0 0.5rem 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

  [class*="clearing-thumbs"] > li
{
     padding: 0.025 0 0.5rem 0;
}
```